# How to verify an oauth2 token on a resource server independent of the identity provider

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, oauth-2.0

My scenario is the one in the next photo.

[image]

The idp is implemented with [OAuth 2.0 Server - Symfony bundle](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com) and is working fine.
Is it possible to verify in the resource server that the token sent by the SPA is valid without having to make a request to the idp in each request from the SPA to the resource server?
Is there a library in Php that allows this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Any good JWT validation library will cache the token signing public keys to ensure good API performance.

Every call to an API provides a `kid` field in the JWT header. This maps to entries in the IDP's Json Web Keyset. Only when a new one is encountered will your API call the IDP to download new keys.

So if there are 10,000 API requests this should result in only 1 request to the IDP. Have a look at this [Symfony tutorial](https://curity.io/resources/learn/symfony-api/), which uses the `lexik-jose` library.